# Close a window and draw the same thing in a new window

Tags: opengl, glfw

In order to create a kind of screensaver
I want to be able to:

1. draw something fullscreen in a GLFW window
2. close the window
3. wait for a while
4. redraw the same exact thing in a new window

I can do that easily but not efficiently. In fact, **I have to do all the initialization again** (context creation, vao, vbo, compile shader...), I don't reuse anything.
It would be fine if the window was just hided from the user, but apparently, you can't hide a fullscreen window with GLFW.

**Does anyone know what can be used again safely, and how?**

---

maybe the code (without reopening a new window) can help you answer my question:

```
...

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    GLFWwindow* window;
    const GLFWvidmode *mode;
    GLenum glew_status;

    float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f
    };
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo;
    GLuint vertexShader;
    GLuint fragmentShader;
    GLuint shaderProgram;

    GLint posAttrib;
    GLint Resolution;
    GLint Time;


    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        return 1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    window = glfwCreateWindow(mode->width, mode->height, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL); // Fullscreen

    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 2;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetInputMode(window,GLFW_CURSOR,GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glew_status = glewInit();
    if (glew_status != GLEW_OK) {
        //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
        fprintf(stderr,"glewInit failed, Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glew_status));
        return 3;
    }

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    vertexShader = LoadShader("/home/celestin/Documents/C/OpenGL/my_openGL/simple_shader/triangle.v.glsl",GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShader = LoadShader("/home/celestin/Documents/C/OpenGL/my_openGL/simple_shader/triangle.f.glsl",GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    Resolution = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "resolution");
    Time = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "time");

    // Clear the screen to black
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glfwSetTime(0.0);

    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        glUniform1f(Time,glfwGetTime());
        glUniform2f(Resolution,mode->width,mode->height);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw a triangle from the 3 vertices
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        // Swap front and back buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you cannot create an initially hidden full screen GLFW window. However, if you are using modern enough OpenGL that you can assume support for framebuffer objects, you can render to a texture using a hidden windowed mode window. The size of the window's default framebuffer won't matter.

If you want to wait between windows, you can save the image data of this texture into RAM and keep it for later.

If you don't mind the lifetimes overlapping, you can you can share this texture into the new window's context with context sharing. This is done with the last argument to `glfwCreateWindow`. Context sharing will also carry over a lot of other object types:

> Objects that may be shared between contexts include buffer objects, program
>   and shader objects, renderbuffer objects, sampler objects, sync objects, and texture
>   objects (except for the texture objects named zero).
>   —[OpenGL 4.5 Specification, chapter 5](https://www.opengl.org/registry/#apispecs)